# Cómo enviar un email mediante una aplicación

Tags: java, apache, java-swing

Quiero realizar una aplicación que mande correos desde una cuenta que tengo de un hosting. Tengo la duda que si se podría hacer poniendo los datos de mi servidor de correo que me ofrece el hosting que tengo o tendría que tener un servicio de correo levantado en un servidor.

El error que me aparece es que no encuentra mi host pero realmente estoy poniendo el host que me indica mi servidor de correo que tengo. Voy a seguir revisando e informo que ocurre por si alguien le ocurre lo mismo.

```
String host = "smtp.1and1.es";
String port = "587";
```

El error que me aparece es

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.1and1.es;
>     nested exception is:

Comment: Delri, bienvenid@! Te invito a pasar por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link para tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de recibir una respuesta.
Si has encontrado una respuesta por tu cuenta, puede que te interese ver [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la librería [JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) para realizar una conexión a tu servidor de correo.

De todas formas, tendrás que comprobar si tu servidor de correo tiene disponible algún protocolo (IMAP, POP3).

En el link que he dejado, tienes la documentación y ejemplos para realizar la conexión.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, he revisado haciéndolo con Java mail pero no conecta con SMTP de mi servidor me aparece un mensaje de error. Que indica que no encuentra mi SMTP host. Tengo que revisar el código bien haber que realmente ocurre. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: IMAP y POP3 no son protocolos para enviar email, sino para consultar mails recibidos. Para enviar correo se usa SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buen día como te comentaron puedes hacer uso de las librerias :JavaMail y Java Activation Framework (JAF)

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendHTMLEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {

     //direccion de  destinatario
      String to = "destinatario@gmail.com";

      // direccion de quien envia correo
      String from = "remitente@gmail.com";

      // host
      String host = "localhost";

      // leer properties con datos autenticacion
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // servidor smtp
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      //obtener session
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Ccrear un objeto MimeMessage
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // agrega remitente
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

         // agrega destinatario
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

         // asunto
         message.setSubject("Asunto de correo!");

         // mensaje como html
         message.setContent("<h1>Mensaje actual. ...</h1>", "text/html" );

         // Se envia mensaje por mail
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Correo enviado exitosamente....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Properties:

```
props.setProperty("mail.user", "myuser");
 props.setProperty("mail.password", "mypwd");
```